# Using MailDir as a Backend for Gnus

Tags: emacs, maildir, gnus

I am using offlineimap to sync my gmail account to a locak maildir, then using gnus to read that directory everything is fine but gnus uses its own flags for marking read unread status of messages and they are not synced back to gmail. is there a way to force gnus to use standart maildir flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the situation has not improved about nnmaildir and gnus since [this](http://groups.google.com/group/linux.debian.user/msg/7594165a2b6d1c49?pli=1).

For this exact situation, I'm now using mutt, setting Emacs as its editor.

Answer (score 7):

I use offlineimap and dovecot to download and serve my mail locally. I also use GNUS. Getting dovecot to work kept me from using GNUS for quite a while since GNUS's support for maildir is so lousy. This is what I needed to make dovecot work:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Mail:LAYOUT=fs:INBOX=~/Mail/INBOX
```

One of the really nice parts of my solution is that I have a real and working offline sync, so that when the network is unavailable (approximate 80% of the time while on campus) I still can check and sort my mail.

Answer (score 6):

This [has been fixed](http://xn--9dbdkw.se/diary/getting_nnmaildir_to_play_nice_with_offlineimap/index.en.html) in nnmaildir in Gnus trunk as of 2012-09-05. The fix appeared in the Gnus version released with Emacs 24.3.

Comment: your blog entry mentioned some issues with gnus when handling maildirs with tens of thousands of messages. The blog entry was from a couple years ago. Have things changed since?

Comment: No, I haven't worked on that since then. I ended up [writing my own IMAP client](https://github.com/legoscia/bic) instead. (It's mostly functional, but still missing a lot of expected features.)

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to use a local imap server (as dovecot) to look at your maildir, and to use gnus to access to this imap server.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Maildir.html) is everything the official manual has to say about maildirs and GNUS - I personally couldn't find there what you're looking for, but then again I'm a mew user, maybe you'll notice something I didn't. I hear, though, that [Wanderlust](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/06/e-mail-with-wanderlust.html) has the best maildir support of all the Emacs mail readers.